# How can I add a button to Windows Explorer. (not to IE)

Tags: delphi, api, windows-explorer

I want to add a button to Win Exp. toolbar and run a script file with the button. How can I do it in Delphi? Or may be Win API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you need is to write a toolbar for Explorer :). There are a lot of articles about implementation of the toolbar:
[one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx?fid=3788&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=301&select=1466953)
[two](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/IEToolbar.aspx)
[three](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/video.php)
[four (in delphi)](http://indodelphi.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/add-a-button-to-the-internet-explorer-toolbar/)

Comment: Windows Explorer, he said. Not Internet Explorer.

Comment: gabr and SimaWB, First of all toolbars for IE and Windows Explorer are almost the same. And if you look at the first link more attentive you will see that the target there is Windows Explorer. Toolbars for IE and WE uses the same BandObject's.

Comment: Also if you install toolbar for IE you will be able to see it in WE too via View->Toolbars. So all information that you need to create a button and add it to WE is provided or you prefer full complete step-by-step guide for your case?

Comment: Thanks zihotki. But I don't want to create new toolbar. Only add new button to Standart Toolbar of WE. But may be I must add new toolbar for quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Shell+ (ShellPlus) components could help with this?  (Not proven myself -- just a thought to research).  I do believe they will let you add a new toolbar, at the very least, modify the right-click menu.  What kind of script are you needing to run?

Comment: Thanks Jamo. 
I want to run my program with the button. Or run Command Prompt.